# Extraction of data from consecutive hovers on several divs from dynamic tables

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract data from some  elements present in a row of each table(there are different tables). This data appears in a new  when hovered on it. This extracted data in then stored in an excel sheet.

[Website screenshot to collect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX6zE.jpg)

In excel, there should be different data in each row but I am getting duplicate. I guess it is beacause of scolling and time taken by hovered  are not working properly. I tried many approches like "visibility_of_element_located", "presence_of_element_located", time.sleep(), WebDriverWait to introduce delay and proper scrolling for the two but still the same output.
[Output of scrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k26Jx.png)

```py
extracted_data = []
try:
    #fetching <div> in each table
    entries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="employees"]/table[*]/div')
    #looping through
    for entry in entries:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(entry).perform()
        time.sleep(4)    
        employee_details = entry.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[starts-with(@id, "info-")]')
    print(employee_details)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 200);")
        #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});", entry)
        details = employee_details.text
        lines = details.split('\n')[:6]
        extracted_data.append(lines)
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    print("Element no longer available in the DOM")

driver.quit()

#Saving into excelsheet
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Email", "DOB", "Salary", "Job Title", "Location"])
    for line in extracted_data:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Printing employee details in console found that:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79cfd2f045d61824e5431a05c99efe5d", element="88538D1110924CD1778F62D52ACCED05_element_52")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79cfd2f045d61824e5431a05c99efe5d", element="88538D1110924CD1778F62D52ACCED05_element_52")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79cfd2f045d61824e5431a05c99efe5d", element="88538D1110924CD1778F62D52ACCED05_element_52")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79cfd2f045d61824e5431a05c99efe5d", element="88538D1110924CD1778F62D52ACCED05_element_62")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79cfd2f045d61824e5431a05c99efe5d", element="88538D1110924CD1778F62D52ACCED05_element_65")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="79cfd2f045d61824e5431a05c99efe5d", element="88538D1110924CD1778F62D52ACCED05_element_68")>
```

First three objects are same and next three objects are different.